# Creating Model instance with three nested models? Django Rest 3.1

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have 3 connected models: User -> UserProfile -> BuyerProfile, and when a user makes an account, I want a User to be made, then a UserProfile, then a BuyerProfile. I'm using a ModelSerializer, but when I use the browsable api and make a post, I get:

```
{
    "userprofile": {
        "user": [
            "This field is required."
        ]
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how to do this?

```
class BuyerProfileViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = BuyerProfile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BuyerProfileSerializer
```

Serializers:

```
    class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = User
            fields = ('username',)

class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    user = UserSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('user', 'bio','prof_type')

class BuyerProfileSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    userprofile = UserProfileSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = BuyerProfile
        fields = ('userprofile', 'company','sitename')
```

Comment: 1. Please show what data serializer receives. 2. Please add restframework version to question.

Comment: What do you mean "what the data serializer recieves"? Do you mean a different serializer? I added the version too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add parameter `required=False` into your instantiation of the `UserProfileSerializer`:

```
 userprofile = UserProfileSerializer(required=False)
```

Comment: If I do that, then the user instance is never created and saved in the database. I want to first create the user, then the userprofile, and finally a BuyerProifle

Comment: Yeah, `required=False` just makes the field optional.  What JSON post object are you sending?

Comment: I'm testing it with the brower api using the html form

Comment: Weird, so I submitted as json this time and it looks like the 'user' fields are now included. Any idea why the data would appear so different between the json vs html form representations?

Comment: Yeah, I've seen a few issues with the html form.  It is doing some guessing , especially for nested fields.  If you look at the request using your debugger (Chrome's debugger network tab?)  then you can see what is actually getting sent to the server.  I'm not sure the html form supports the nested interface.... I simply don't use it for nested work, myself.